# Matching values to corresponding columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, key-value

I have a data frame in R that needs cleaning. The problem is that the data has the corresponding columns names inside the values (inside the quotation marks; it corresponds to the column names). Then I want only keep the numeric values to the right of the `:`.

Here is the original dataframe:

```
> df
      col1      col2     col3      col4      
 1  "4":50    "2":10    "1":0    "3":20        
 2   "2":5   "4":-50                                 
 3    NULL                                         
 4  "4":65    "3":45  "2":-15     "1":0
```

Desired output:

```
 > new_df
      col1      col2     col3      col4      
 1       0        10       20        50        
 2       0         5        0       -50                                 
 3    NULL                                         
 4       0       -15       45        65
```

For convenience, here is the output for `dput(df)`.

```
dput(df)
    structure(list(`1` = c("\"4\":50", "\"2\":5", "NULL", "\"4\":65"
), `2` = c("\"2\":10", "\"4\":-50", "", "\"3\":45"), `3` = c("\"1\":0", 
"", "", "\"2\":-15"), `4` = c("\"3\":20", "", "", "\"1\":0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: This is a "key-value" problem. You might try searching on "[r] [key-value]". SO's search function lets you put square-brackets around "tags".

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. Seems pretty clear to me. I did have a bit of difficulty getting the data entry step to succeed but that wasn't the question and the path to a successful and tested answer seems failry open now.

Comment: What you show as the original data frame doesn't look as a data frame to me Would you mind sharing it with `dput(df)` so it is copy/pasteable for us?

Comment: @Z.Springirth: You should learn to post material additions or corrections to your answer by using the SO [edit] facilities. Don't use comments for that purpose.

Comment: @Gregor I've posted the dput(df) output in the original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dataframe that is as close as one can get for that data. All rows need to have either a value or an NA so the third row has:

```
3 "NULL" ""    ""   ""
```

The quotes and separators needed to be specially handled since that data arrangement was not easily inputted with `read.table`:

```
df <- read.table(text=' col1,      col2,     col3,      col4      
 1,  "4":50 ,   "2":10 ,  "1":0,    "3":20        
 2,   "2":5,   "4":-50                                 
 3,    NULL                                         
 4 , "4":65,    "3":45,  "2":-15,     "1":0', sep=",", header=TRUE,quote="\"",fill=TRUE,strip.white=TRUE)
```

Now one can work on each line separately and position the values at the location of the keys:

My first try was with:

```
df2 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) if(x=="NULL"){ c("NULL",NA,NA,NA) } else 
                             { z <- rep(0,4)
                               for (i in x){
                                   z[as.numeric(sub( ":.+$", "", i))] <- sub("^.+:", "", i) }
                               return(z)})
```

Which if you look at it sideways is almost correct. Since R returns results from `apply` in "column-major" arrangement, you often need to transpose:

```
 df3 <- t(df2)
 df3
  [,1]   [,2]  [,3] [,4] 
1 "0"    "10"  "20" "50" 
2 "0"    "5"   "0"  "-50"
3 "NULL" NA    NA   NA   
4 "0"    "-15" "45" "65"
```

@Z.Springirth: Please don't complain about the fact that these are character values. You are the one who specified a"NULL" value in this output. "NULL" is not a legitimate numeric value and columns in dataframes must be of the same class. So one character value in a column forces all the value to be character.

This gives you the appearance of success but I warn you that the columns are factor rather than character. The entries will not behave like numbers unless you coerce them (individually) to numeric:

```
> as.data.frame(df3)
    V1   V2   V3   V4
1    0   10   20   50
2    0    5    0  -50
3 NULL <NA> <NA> <NA>
4    0  -15   45   65
```

If you are willing to give up the "NULL" requirement, then this might complete the process:

```
> df4 <-  as.data.frame(df3,stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
> df4[] <- lapply(df4, as.numeric)
Warning message:
In lapply(df4, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion
> df4
  V1  V2 V3  V4
1  0  10 20  50
2  0   5  0 -50
3 NA  NA NA  NA
4  0 -15 45  65
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer! I probably should have just transformed the "NULL" characters to all NAs. In fact I could have probably removed that third row too for simplicity purposes. But I also have too many rows to go though one by one, would you have a suggestion for that issue?

Comment: I don't understand the last part. What is mean by "too many rows to go though one by one"?Any solution is of necessity going to go through the rows one by one. If you mean doing editing "by hand" to remove them, then just remove offending rows by using `readLines` and removing them with a negation of a `grepl` value as an index.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I meant I have 3,000 plus rows of data that I need to clean up.

Comment: So I've answered the question, then? Or do you need to post another question?.... after searching of course.

Comment: MANY THANKS 42-!!! It works great! Obviously I still have a lot to learn. Thank you again!